# jQuery to flip arrow icon based on collapse position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for some jQuery that will flip my arrow icon from down to up based on the position of the collapsed state.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading customize">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#personnel-menu" href="#personnel">
        Personnel
        <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>
      </a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="personnel" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <ul class="list-unstyled stripped">
        <li><a href="#">Users</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When in "open" position, this line `<div id="personnel" class="panel-collapse collapse">` will change to `<div id="personnel" class="panel-collapse collapse in">`. Adds "in".

While in this position, with "in" `<div id="personnel" class="panel-collapse collapse in">` I would like to take the line `<span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>` (a few lines above the former) and change the class *fa-angle-down* to **fa-angle-up**.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just use CSS for that purpose?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example, I assume you're using [`Bootstrap's Collapse`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) plugin with [`Font Awesome`](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/).

If it's the case, perhaps you could try hooking into the `Collapse`'s `shown.bs.collapse` and `hidden.bs.collapse` events and do your manipulation (flipping the arrow icon) there.

For example:

```
$('#personnel-menu').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function (event) {      
  var arrow = $('#' + event.target.id).parent().find('i');    
  arrow.removeClass('fa-angle-down');
  arrow.addClass('fa-angle-up');
}).on('shown.bs.collapse', function (event) {
  var arrow = $('#' + event.target.id).parent().find('i');        
  arrow.removeClass('fa-angle-up');
  arrow.addClass('fa-angle-down');
});
```

Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pUam7/show/ ([source](http://jsfiddle.net/pUam7/))

Comment: Excellent, thank you! And you are correct on both assumptions - BS and FA

Answer (score 0):

The code to do this is fairly straight forward:

```
var elem = $("#personnel");

if (elem.hasClass("in")) {
    elem.parents(".panel").first().find(".fa-angle-down")
        .removeClass("fa-angle-down")
        .addClass("fa-angle-up");
}
else {
    elem.parents(".panel").first().find(".fa-angle-up")
        .removeClass("fa-angle-up")
        .addClass("fa-angle-down");
}
```

You would trigger this code whenever you want to add the "in" class to the `$("#personel")` object.

However, if you're going to be adding the class anyway, IMO a better way to do it would be to add the class to the `$(".panel")` div - then CSS will take care of the changes for you, eg:

```
.panel .panel-heading .panel-title a i.fa {
    background-color: red;
}
.panel.in .panel-heading .panel-title a i.fa {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Even if you do want to use javascript, then, IMO it's best to add the code to change the class (from `fa-angle-down` to `fa-angle-up` and vice-versa) on whatever event/in whatever function call you are using to add the "in" class to the `$("#personnel")` object.